# Images and Icons for Apps (Android - iOS)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, resources

I am creating my first App for the iOS and Android platforms and want to start with some good icons and images. I do not want to spent a lot of money on them. I also do not have experience with softwares like photoshop to create my own images and icons.

I am trying to find some websites that can provide me with sports related UI resources.

What are some popular/good sites that I can utilize for my project.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this site is about **programming question** and not to have recommandation about tools or libraries. I think it might be better to ask this question on the related Stack Exchange site: [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi, thanks, t don't know that section, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend two sites: [IconArchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/) and [Icon8](http://icons8.com/).

They both have free icon sets that can help you to get you started with your designs!

Cheers

Comment: I was going to post the same one.

Comment: Hi! very good resources! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of resources your looking for, if it's mainly icons I suggest: http://iconfinder.com

If your looking for photo resources I would try http://gettyimage.com